# Некорректно работает конструкция if...else. Телеграм бот

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, telegram, aiogram

Всегда срабатывает `else`, нужно чтобы выводилось сообщение `вы не подписаны`, в случае, если в таблице поле `status == FALSE`, у меня же всегда выводит все то, что в блоке `else`. Используется библиотека `aiogram`.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
async def unsubscribe(message:types.Message):
    if (db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id) == False):
        print (db.get_status(message.from_user.id))
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем с неактивной подпиской (запоминаем)
        await message.answer("Вы не подписаны.")
    else:
        # если юзер есть в базе, то обновляем статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, False)
        #print (db.get_status(message.from_user.id))
        await message.answer("Я тебе больше не нужен...")
        await message.answer_sticker(r'CAACAgIAAxkBAAEBv8Vf-FRnpC5qrQZn2Qwt-rpBs-OJpwACDAEAAhZ8aAPEXuoz0922Fx4E')
        await message.answer("прощай ")
```

db

```
import sqlite3

class SQLighter:

    def __init__(self, database):
        """Подключаемся к БД и сохраняем курсор соединения"""
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(database)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def get_subscriptions(self, status = True):
        """Получаем всех активных подписчиков бота"""
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status` = ?", (status,)).fetchall()

    def subscriber_exists(self, user_id):
        """Проверяем, есть ли уже юзер в базе"""
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_subscriber(self, user_id, status = True):
        """Добавляем нового подписчика"""
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `status`) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id,status))

    def update_subscription(self, user_id, status):
        """Обновляем статус подписки пользователя"""
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `users` SET `status` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (status, user_id))

    def get_status(self, user_id):
        """получаем статус юзера"""
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def close(self):
        """Закрываем соединение с БД"""
        self.connection.close()
```

Comment: Некорректно работает не языковая конструкция, а функция `subscriber_exists` у объекта `db`. Кстати, что это такое и как реализована функция? Из вопроса совсем не понятно.

Comment: @mrEvgenX дополнил

Comment: Распечатайте в функции переменную `result`... Когда вы ожидаете `False`, что в ней записано? Действительно ли там пустой список?

Comment: Или вы там не пустой список хотите? Вы твердите про какой-то `status`, ну дык проверяйте его:) `bool(len(result))` вернет `False`, только если  `result` пустой.

Comment: @mrEvgenX ок, гляну, сейчас отдых ;) 
спасибо, отпишусь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, проверку нужно поменять на `fetchone`:

```
    def subscriber_exists(self, user_id):
        """Проверяем, есть ли уже юзер в базе"""
        with self.connection:
            has = self.cursor.execute('SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchone()
            return bool(has)
```

---

**UPD.**

Если у вас подписчик определяется не только наличием в базе данных, но и статусом, то нужно это проверять (добавьте проверку `status`):

```
    def subscriber_exists(self, user_id):
        """Проверяем, есть ли уже юзер в базе"""
        with self.connection:
            has = self.cursor.execute('SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ? and `status` = 1', (user_id,)).fetchone()
            return bool(has)
```

Или можно подписчика через статус проверять, но для этого нужно **его правильно получать**:

```
    def get_status(self, user_id):
        """получаем статус юзера"""
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT `status` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", (user_id,)).fetchone()
            # Если юзер не был найден
            if result is None:
                return False
            return bool(result[0])
```

Тогда, можно проверить статус так:

```
if not db.get_status(message.from_user.id):
    await message.answer("Вы не подписаны.")
else:
    ...
```

---

**PS.**

И я бы еще условие упростил:

```
if not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id):
    print(db.get_status(message.from_user.id))
    ...
```

Comment: все также, при чем в дебаге ```status``` всегда ```True```, не смотря на то, что в таблице значение меняется

Comment: Должно работать... Что выводит `print(has, bool(has))`? Тот `user_id` точно в базе есть?

Comment: ```has ==  True``` и при подписке и при отписке ...

Comment: @CatException, я просил чтобы вы написали что **именно выводит** в `print`. Чтобы понять что у вас пошло не так, нужно знать что именно вернулось из базы. Вообще, если там не будет результата, т.е. не будет такого пользователя, то должно вернуться `None`, что при `bool(has)` вернет `False`, если же что-то вернулось, то будет `(1,)`, что соответствует `True`. Пруф насчет `None`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone

Comment: @CatException, еще... вы писали про `True` при отписке и подписке. Если у вас отписка эта смена статуса юзера, то конечно же `subscriber_exists` будет `True` возвращать, т.к. вы не удаляете юзера при отписке. Значит, вам подписку нужно проверять не наличием юзера в базе а еще и на статус. Добавлю пример в ответе